# Inserting a node in the front of linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a linked list, now I want to walk through it and each time I advance in it, I move the current node to the beginning of list like this:

```
4 5 3 2 7
5 4 3 2 7
3 5 4 2 7
2 3 5 4 7
7 2 3 5 4
```

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _node {
    int p;
    struct _node *next;
} node;

main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i, n;
    node *nod = NULL;
    node *nod2 = NULL;
    node *nod_tmp = NULL;

    node *nod_next = NULL;
    node *nod_before = NULL;

    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        nod_tmp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        scanf("%d", &nod_tmp->p);
        if (i == 0)
        {
            nod = nod2 = nod_tmp;
        }
        nod2->next = nod_tmp;
        nod2 = nod_tmp;
    }

    nod_tmp = nod;
    while (nod_tmp->next != NULL)
    {
        nod_before = nod_tmp; // save current node
        nod_next = nod_tmp->next->next; // save next node
        nod_before->next = nod_next; // link the previous with the next one
        nod_tmp->next = nod; // point the current node to the beginning of list
    }

    while(nod != NULL)
    {   
        printf("%d\n", nod->p);
        nod = nod->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should not have names with leading underscore in the global namespace, as such names are reserved by the standard.

Comment: So.. you want to reverse a linked list ?

Comment: @David I don't get any output, witch mean there is some thing I am doing wrong.

Comment: @WhozCraig Each time I advance in the list, I have to move the current node to the beginning of list.

Comment: @SIFE yeah, and when you're done, look at the first list and the last list. Am i incorrect that they should be reversed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nod_tmp = nod->next;
nod_before= nod;
while (nod_tmp != NULL)
{
     nod_before->next = nod_tmp->next;
     nod_tmp->next = nod;
     nod = nod_tmp;
     nod_tmp = nod_before->next;
}
```

Change your second loop to this loop above. Note that `node_tmp` points to the second node after the head and `nod_before` points to the first node. This way you avoid infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

Think seriously about what the while-loop reversing your list is actually doing. For example, assuming we had this list:

```
1 --> 2 --> 3 -->null
```

Lets walk your while-loop code:

```
nod_tmp = nod; // nod and nod_tmp now point to 1
while (nod_tmp->next != NULL)
{
    nod_before = nod_tmp; // nod_before, nod_tmp, and nod all point to 1
    nod_next = nod_tmp->next->next; // nod_next points to 3
    nod_before->next = nod_next; // 1-->3 
    nod_tmp->next = nod; // 1-->1
}
```

The first node (still referenced by nod_tmp) now points to itself. This will not only cause an infinite spin on your while-condition, it also leaks the rest of the memory in your list.

Answer (score 0):

Inifinite loop right here:

```
while (nod_tmp->next != NULL)
    {
        nod_before = nod_tmp; // save current node
        nod_next = nod_tmp->next->next; // save next node
        nod_before->next = nod_next; // link the previous with the next one
        nod_tmp->next = nod; // point the current node to the beginning of list
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _node {
    int p;
    struct _node *next;
} node;

main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i, n;
    node *nod = NULL;
    node *nod2 = NULL; //header of the linked list
    node *nod_tmp = NULL;

    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        nod_tmp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        scanf("%d", &nod_tmp->p);
        nod_tmp->next = nod2;
        nod2 = nod_tmp;
    }

    nod = nod2;

    printf("Linked list order before reversing:  ");
    while(nod != NULL)
    {   
        printf("%d  ", nod->p);
        nod = nod->next;
    }
    printf("\n");

    nod = nod2;
    while (nod!=NULL && nod->next != NULL)
    {
        nod_tmp = nod2;
        nod2 = nod->next;
        nod->next = nod2->next;
        nod2->next = nod_tmp;
    }

    nod = nod2;

    printf("Linked list order after reversing:  ");
    while(nod != NULL)
    {   
        printf("%d ", nod->p);
        nod = nod->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```